# Wrong number of item passed 13, placement implies 1 while pivot using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am getting the above error if I add 'column' in the pivot table function of pandas. Without 'Column' it works fine.

```
df1 = {'Material Code':['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'], 'Material Desc':['ABC','XYZ','QWE','ERT','MNH','LKJ','HGF'], 'Vendor':['Vendor_1','Vendor_2','Vendor_3','Vendor_4','Vendor_5','Vendor_6','Vendor_7'],'Currency':['INR','INR','INR','INR','USD','USD','USD'],'Months':['JAN','FEB','MAR','JAN','FEB','JAN','APR'], 'GRN Quantity':[100, 200, 500, 400, 100, 100, 500], 'Purchase Price':[10, 15, 20, 45, 45, 12, 15]}
index_data = ['Material Code', 'Material Desc', 'Vendor', 'Currency']
column_data = 'Months'
pf = pd.pivot_table(data=df1,index=index_data, columns=column_data,values=values_data,aggfunc={"GRN Quantity":np.sum, "Purchase Price":np.sum}, fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

It would be great help, I am struck mid of a project. Thanks You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to create the dataframe and set `values_data`. `pivot_table` requires a dataframe as data not a dict.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)

index_data = ['Material Code', 'Material Desc', 'Vendor', 'Currency']
column_data = 'Months'
values_data = df1.columns.difference(index_data + [column_data])

months = dict(zip(['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG',
                   'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'], range(12)))

pf = pd.pivot_table(data=df1, index=index_data, columns=column_data,
                    values=values_data, fill_value=0,
                    aggfunc={"GRN Quantity":np.sum, "Purchase Price":np.sum}) \
       .swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(level=0, axis=1, key=lambda x: [months[i] for i in x]).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> pf

Months Material Code Material Desc    Vendor Currency          JAN                         FEB                         MAR                         APR               
                                                      GRN Quantity Purchase Price GRN Quantity Purchase Price GRN Quantity Purchase Price GRN Quantity Purchase Price
0                  A           ABC  Vendor_1      INR          100             10            0              0            0              0            0              0
1                  B           XYZ  Vendor_2      INR            0              0          200             15            0              0            0              0
2                  C           QWE  Vendor_3      INR            0              0            0              0          500             20            0              0
3                  D           ERT  Vendor_4      INR          400             45            0              0            0              0            0              0
4                  E           MNH  Vendor_5      USD            0              0          100             45            0              0            0              0
5                  F           LKJ  Vendor_6      USD          100             12            0              0            0              0            0              0
6                  G           HGF  Vendor_7      USD            0              0            0              0            0              0          500             15
```

Comment: Thanks for the revert. I was using 'Months' as value data, I just skipped to mention in the above codes. It was showing  the same error.

Comment: No you can't use Months for columns and for values.

Comment: How to reverse the column alignment? Like Making it Group By Months ?